# Given finite sets $A$ and $B$, is $\max(|A|,|B|) = |A \cap B| \iff A = B$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given finite sets $A$ and $B$, is
$$
\max(|A|,|B|) = |A \cap B| \iff A = B
$$
true? Here is my attempt to prove that this statement is true. To prove
$$
\max(|A|,|B|) = |A \cap B| \Longleftarrow A = B,
$$
suppose that $A = B$. Then,
$$
\max(|A|,|B|) = \max(|A|,|A|) = |A| = |A \cap A| = |A|.
$$
To prove
$$
\max(|A|,|B|) = |A \cap B| \Longrightarrow A = B,
$$
suppose that $\max(|A|,|B|) = |A \cap B|$. If $|A| \geq |B|$, then
$$
|A| = |A \cap B|.
$$
At this point, I am not sure if this implies that $A = A \cap B$. Even if it does, this would then imply that $A \subset B$, but I am not able to show that $B \subset A$ as well assuming that $|A| \geq |B|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote, wlog $|A|\ge |B|$.
Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$ (and we deal with finite sets), we have $|A\cap B|=|A|\iff A\cap B=A$. But $A\cap B=A$ is equivalent to $A\subseteq B$ and that means that $|A|\le |B|$. Together with $|A|\ge |B|$, this gives $|A|=|B|$. Again, $A\subseteq B$ together with $|A|=|B|$ implies (for finite sets) that $A=B$.